# How to simplify the generated user password on registration in DotNetNuke 5.6.3

Tags: dotnetnuke

When registering as a new user in a DotNetNuke 5.6.3 site, the **user entered password is ignored** (no matter how complex it is - it certainly meets the system requirements) and a safe but ugly password is created.

Two related questions:

1. What could be the reason why the password the user desires is ignored and replaced by an auto-generated one?
2. Is there a way to tell DotNetNuke to create a less safe (and thus less ugly) password, maybe just letters, omitting special characters (it's a customer requirement, so please no discussion about safety on the net ;-) )

The AspNetSqlMembershipProvider settings in web.config are as follows:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
enablePasswordReset="true" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
applicationName="DotNetNuke" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this very same problem and jumped through the very same hoops.

**I ended up modifying the default membership provider for DotNetNuke.**

1) Download the DNN 5.6.3 source

2) Open main solution, navigate to `/library/providers/membershipproviders/ASPNetMembershipProvider/AMPNetMembershipProvider.vb` Line ~826

3) Edit function `Public Overloads Overrides Function GeneratePassword(ByVal length As Integer) As String`

4) Replace its contents with: `Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 7)` or whatever password generation code that you wish to use.

5) Compile

6) Copy the resulting DLL to your deployed DNN installation

**Notes**

- I use the NewGUID() because it mixes in letters and numbers, my users are such that any punctuation is going to throw them
- I have my DNN source hooked to subversion. I recommend this if you modify the core
- I also recommend inserting `''Begin OLAF Modifications` and `END OLAF Modifications` before and after your modifications, so that in a few months when you move to DNN 6 that you are able to make the same modifications in the DNN 6 source by searching for `OLAF Modifications` in the DNN 5.6.3 source
- Modifying the DNN source is a last-ditch solution, but I believe it is required in this case

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution (good to know I'm not the only one)! It works (or it's going to, respectively)!

Answer (score 1):

**Part 2** of my question has been answered by **hamlin11**. I found the **solution for part 1** (just in case someone is interested):

There is a hidden CheckBox in DesktopModules\Admin\Security\User.ascx named 'chkRandom' which is set to True in my installation, but invisible at the same time (don't know what influences that - weird setup, the user never knows why her password gets replaced by a random one). Setting this to false solves the issue.

Comment: The ability to set a random password is only available when admins create user accounts.  When user's register for themselves, using a random password makes no sense and is therefore hidden.  The mystery is how the box gets checked.  I installed 5.6.3 and didn't have this problem, and my review of the 5.6.3 code shows only 1 line that sets the checked value, and it always sets it to false, only the UI can actually check the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I have no idea why, but the random password checkbox has been set to Checked="True" in the aspx file. I'll try to find out who did this (*if* it was someone from our team) or if it has been set to True when it was installed.

Comment: Looking more closely the checkbox is checked by default in the .ascx file.  Now I don't understand why I don't get the same problem on a clean install of 5.6.3.